# phpmyadmin forbidden in Red Hat Enterprise Linux running on Amazon Web Services EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, phpmyadmin, rhel

I am unable to access phpmyadmin in my server. I'm getting Forbidden.

Os version : Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.3 (Maipo)

I have checked answers in stackoverflow but, I'm unable to resolve my issue.
I installed phpmyadmin using command line.
running phpmyadmin Version information: 4.5.4.1

I have modified values in /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf

My server is running on Amazon Web Services free tier.

here is the content present in phpMyAdmin.conf

```
Alias /phpMyAdmin /usr/share/phpMyAdmin
Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpMyAdmin

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

#   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
# Apache 2.4
#    <RequireAny>
#  Require ip 127.0.0.1

#    Require ip ::1
# </RequireAny>
# </IfModule>
# <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
# Apache 2.2
Order Deny,Allow
# Deny from All
Allow from all
# Allow from 127.0.0.1

# Allow from ::1
# AllowOverride all
# Require all granted
# </IfModule>
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/>
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
# Apache 2.4
<RequireAny>

Require ip ::1
</RequireAny>
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
# Apache 2.2
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from All

Allow from ::1
</IfModule>
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/libraries/>
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from All
Allow from None
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/lib/>
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from All
Allow from None
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/frames/>
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from All
Allow from None
</Directory>
```

Comment: You must ensure that apache is running before going to access the phpmyadmin. Try to post the problem with log, where as in your case it might be apache-log. So that one can help you on where was the problem exist rather-than searching around the bush.

Answer (score 0):

can you tell me what version of apache you are using apache 2.4 or apache 2.2 .
assuming 2.4 
add to you httpd.conf

```
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

your below settings is restricting your access from browser .

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from All
Allow from ::1
```

Restart your httpd (apache)

Comment: I'm using Apache/2.4.6 ( Red Hat Enterprise Linux ). I pasted phpmyadmin folder( downloaded from www.phpmyadmin.net ) inside /var/www/html/    Now I'm able to use phpmyadmin.  Before this I used YUM INSTALL PHPMYADMIN and got struck.

Comment: I don't think that is the proper resolution to the problem you faced and yum is enough powerful to install PHPMyAdmin properly. Anyway glad to see yours working.

Comment: Yes, this didn't solved my issue. After pasting that phpmyadmin inside html, I'm unable to access it, until I commented this line....    Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpMyAdmin.     If try to access myadmin like this..   <my ip address>/phpMyAdmin . I'm still getting forbidden error.